# Refresh js and css every session

Tags: c#, asp.net

i want that a user make the login, the js and css are force to refresh themself

How can i do?

Thanks

Comment: you mean that after the user logs in, the JS and CSS should refresh?

Answer (score 1):

You mean you want to invalidate the cache for some `script.js` or `style.css` files?
You can add dummy GET parameter like this:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css?needrefresh12345" />
```

Or if you log in users without page reload (Ajax) you can add that dummy argument to the `src` and `href`  attributes with Javascript.

Answer (score 0):

For forcefully refresh css, you can dynamically load css  using jquery.